# AssetInputStream.read() always returning -1

Tags: android, inputstream, android-contentresolver, android-assets

I'm writing an application that needs to read two image files for various purposes.

One of the image files is received through an intent-filter, and I open it in this way (note: `mIntent` is the result of `getIntent()`):

```
mFileUri = (Uri) mIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
mInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(mFileUri);
```

Then reading mInputStream works as expected.

The problem is reading the second image file: it's `Uri` (converted using `toString()`) is written in a shared preference, I get the value and use `Uri.parse()` to restore it, as "default value" argument in the `getString()` call I use the `Uri` of a local resource located in the assets subdirectory (`android.resource` scheme). The way I try to read it is the same, using `getContentResolver().openInputStream()`, but something goes wrong: calling `read()` on the returned `InputStream` always return `-1`. I've also tried `getAssets().open()`, but it doesn't work, either with an `android.resource` or a `content` scheme `Uri`.
Note: with the intent-received file I use `read(byte[])`, while with the second one I use `read()`.

So, here is my question: why does this happen and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned

Comment: @pskink        I used the "step in" debugger command and I've seen that the "length" is equal to the file length and the "position" is zero. I've also tried to call `reset()`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: what length? if read() returns -1 it means that you reached EOF, if it is after first read() it means that stream is empty

Comment: @pskink        The `available()` method of the `InputStream` returns `2746` (the exact size of the file), but the first `read()` returns `-1`

Comment: Reading the sources of the native method used by the class, I've seen a comment saying that there's not `feof()` or `ferror()` so `0` either in case of I/O errors and EOF. Source: http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/Asset.cpp#436 (the comment I'm talking about is at line *481*)

Comment: btw what is the uri of question? is that file really non empty?

Comment: @pskink   It's a JPEG image of 2746 bytes, located both in the assets and in the drawable folder (I use it as a placeholder in an `ImageView`), the `Uri` is valid, because passing it to `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` returns an `InputStream` that works when passed to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`, but not when trying to `read()` (right after opening it, and when `available()` returns the file size).

Comment: i see, so what uri is it like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right: **it is a bug in the `AssetInputStream` implementation** due to the lack of distinction between EOF and I/O errors in the native method `_FileAsset::read(void *, size_t)`.

The result is that reading from `AssetInputStream` is possible only by using `read(byte[])` or `read(byte[], int, int)`.

Answer (score 0):

you *can* read assets using 'int read()' method, try:

```
AssetManager mgr = getAssets();
try {
    InputStream is = mgr.open("test.txt");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate 'is': " + is);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate note 'is' is android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream");
    int c;
    while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate " + (char) c);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and the output (for a file assets/test.txt which contains bytes "qwertyuiop" is:

D/Test    (  872): onCreate 'is': android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream
D/Test    (  872): onCreate note 'is' is android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream
D/Test    (  872): onCreate q
D/Test    (  872): onCreate w
D/Test    (  872): onCreate e
D/Test    (  872): onCreate r
D/Test    (  872): onCreate t
D/Test    (  872): onCreate y
D/Test    (  872): onCreate u
D/Test    (  872): onCreate i
D/Test    (  872): onCreate o
D/Test    (  872): onCreate p

but as you did not provide the Uri you are using to create your AssetInputStream i cannot reproduce your exact error.